# Преобразование в Xamarine

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Такой вопрос: есть код в Xamarine, который проводит вычисления по нажатию кнопки и получает некоторое число в формате String, выводя его на экран. Как сделать так, чтобы это же число можно было подставлять в следующий метод, в котором он нужен для продолжения счета?

1. Получение первого значения:

```
private void Button_Clicked_InfVol(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    double n1 = Convert.ToDouble(num1.Text); 
    int n3 = Convert.ToInt32(num3.Text);
    result1.Text = (((n1 * 40 + 70) + (n1 * 8 * n3))).ToString();
}
```

Его xaml:

```
<Label Text="Calculator of Volume" Margin="5" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="20" HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <Entry x:Name="num1" WidthRequest="100" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="kg"/>
    <Entry x:Name="num3" WidthRequest="100" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="%"/>
</StackLayout>
<Label x:Name="result1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black"/>
<Button Text="Calculate" Clicked="Button_Clicked_InfVol"/>
```

2. Код, где нужен результат виде числа:

```
private void Button_Clicked_InfSpeed(object sender1, EventArgs s) 
{
    try
    {
        double n2 = Convert.ToDouble(num2.Text);
        result2.Text = ((result1 /2) / n2).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", exc.ToString(), "Ok");
    };
```

И его xaml:

```
<Label Text="Calculator of Speed" Margin="5" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
<Label Text="50% вводится за 6-12 часов" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10" HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <Entry x:Name="num2" WidthRequest="100" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="hour"/>
</StackLayout>
<Label x:Name="result2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
<Button Text="Calculate" Clicked="Button_Clicked_InfSpeed"/>
```

Comment: Так и бери из result1 свой результат только конвертируй его в число!!!

Comment: Извините,я просто новичок, но так как он в войде, его значение метод не возвращает. А если менять метод, VS ругается на сигнатуру

Comment: Не надо менять сигнатуры, просто во втором методе используйте result1.Text и конвертируйте его в нужный тип

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое всем.